# Android lap timing app

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, xamarin-studio

I'm just starting out developing my first Android app that will record lap times and I was just after some advice on which way to go, Database (SQLite) or txt files?

I want to be able to save coordinates for a given track and then record the lap times as the user passes those coordinates. I have a windows form app that I want to import the data in to as well. The existing win form app can already import csv files.

I was thinking, from what I've already read online, of saving track coordinates to a internal txt file and writing the lap times to a external txt file. Then the user could plug the phone into their pc and import the txt/csv files in to the win form app.

The win form app uses a sql ce database by the way.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

P.S. I'm using Xamarin Studio.

Comment: if you will be using a large data use `SQLite` otherwise use `Shared Preference`.

Comment: I would opt for SQLite. Use an ORM wrapper, like SQLite.Net.Pcl and define the classes you want to save. Then I would use TCP and UDP sockets to transfer the data to desktop. Simple and efficient, and much less hassle for the end user.